# Connection of PostgreSQL database with corda

Tags: postgresql, corda, pg

How to connect **PostgreSQL database** using pg admin to corda instead of H2 database ?
What are the changes to be done in node.conf file before the nodes are up ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PostgreSQL instead of H2 as the Corda node's database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419854/using-postgresql-instead-of-h2-as-the-corda-nodes-database)

Comment: See above. This is indeed a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, all you need is adding the followings `node.conf` file after you have generated your node.

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://[HOST]:[PORT]/postgres"
    dataSource.user = [USER]
    dataSource.password = [PASSWORD]
}

database = {
    transactionIsolationLevel = READ_COMMITTED
}
```

And please remember to wrap all the string values with double quotes (eg. `"Username"`, `"Password"`)