# Unable to connect Corda node to Postgres with SSL

Tags: corda

My Postgres DB in GCP (Google Cloud Platform) only accepts connections over SSL.
I tried the below inside my `node.conf` without any success:

```
dataSourceProperties {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://db-private-ip:5432/my_node"
    dataSource.ssl = true
    dataSource.sslMode = verify-ca
    dataSource.sslRootCert = "/opt/corda/db-certs/server-ca.pem"
    dataSource.sslCert = "/opt/corda/db-certs/client-cert.pem"
    dataSource.sslKey = "/opt/corda/db-certs/client-key.pem"
    dataSource.user = my_node_db_user
    dataSource.password = my_pass
}
```

I'm sure that the keys (sslMode, sslRootCert, sslCert, and sslKey) are acceptable in `node.conf` (even though they are not mentioned anywhere in Corda docs), because in the logs I didn't get any errors that those key are not recognized.
I get this error when I try to start the node:

```
[ERROR] 21:58:48+0000 [main] pool.HikariPool. - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. [errorCode=zmhrwq, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/zmhrwq]
[ERROR] 21:58:48+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.: Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database. [errorCode=18t70u2, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3/18t70u2]
```

I tried adding `?ssl=true` to the end of the data source URL as suggested in ([Azure Postgres Database requires SSL Connection from Corda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326843/azure-postgres-database-requires-ssl-connection-from-corda)) but that didn't fix the problem.

Also for the same values I'm able to use the psql client to connect my VM to the DB:

```
psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem hostaddr=db-private-ip user=some-user dbname=some-pass"
```

Comment: Is it OpenSource or Enterprise?

Comment: It's OpenSource.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the JDBC driver cannot read the key from a PEM file, it has to be converted to a DER file using:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -in client-key.pem -outform DER -nocrypt -out client-key.der

chmod 400 client-key.der
chown corda:corda client-key.der
```

More details here: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1364

So the correct config should look like this:

```
dataSourceProperties {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    dataSource.url = "jdbc:postgresql://db-private-ip:5432/db-name"
    dataSource.ssl = true
    dataSource.sslMode = verify-ca
    dataSource.sslRootCert = "/opt/corda/db-certs/server-ca.pem"
    dataSource.sslCert = "/opt/corda/db-certs/client-cert.pem"
    dataSource.sslKey = "/opt/corda/db-certs/client-key.der"
    dataSource.user = db-user-name
    dataSource.password = db-user-pass
}
```

Comment: Full details are here: https://blog.b9lab.com/enabling-corda-security-with-nodes-configuration-file-412ce6a4371c