# Corda node not able to connect to external DB - k8s

Tags: postgresql, containers, corda

Facing issue when deploying corda network with k8s.Node is not able to connect to the external DB.
DB container is up and running. below are the configs

**Node.conf**

```
dataSourceProperties  {
        dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
        dataSource  {
                url = "jdbc:postgresql://xx.xx.xx.xx:5432/notarydb"
                user = user1
                password = "test"
        }
}

database {
    transactionIsolationLevel=READ_COMMITTED
    initialiseSchema=true
    runMigration=true
}
```

**Error**

```
[ERROR] 17:56:26+0530 [main] postgresql.Driver. - Connection error:  [errorCode=zmhrwq, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.4/zmhrwq]
[ERROR] 17:56:26+0530 [main] common.BaseDataSource. - Failed to create a Non-Pooling DataSource from PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.1.4 for admin at jdbc:postgresql://1xx.xx.xx.xx:5432/notarydb?prepareThreshold=5&preparedStatementCacheQueries=256&preparedStatementCacheSizeMiB=5&databaseMetadataCacheFields=65536&databaseMetadataCacheFieldsMiB=5&defaultRowFetchSize=0&binaryTransfer=true&readOnly=false&binaryTransferEnable=&binaryTransferDisable=&unknownLength=2147483647&logUnclosedConnections=false&disableColumnSanitiser=false&tcpKeepAlive=false&loginTimeout=30&connectTimeout=10&socketTimeout=0&cancelSignalTimeout=10&receiveBufferSize=-1&sendBufferSize=-1&ApplicationName=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver&useSpnego=false&gsslib=auto&sspiServiceClass=POSTGRES&allowEncodingChanges=false&targetServerType=any&loadBalanceHosts=false&hostRecheckSeconds=10&preferQueryMode=extended&autosave=never&reWriteBatchedInserts=false: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
[ERROR] 17:56:26+0530 [main] pool.HikariPool. - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. [errorCode=zmhrwq, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.4/zmhrwq]
[ERROR] 17:56:26+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node registration: Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database. [errorCode=18t70u2, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/ENT/4.4/18t70u2]
[ERROR] 17:56:26+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Could not connect to the database. Please check your JDBC connection URL, or the connectivity to the database.
```

Comment: 1. make sure the connection url is correct. 2. add the schema name using currentSchema=my_schema to the connection url. 3. make sure your driver is added to the drivers directory. 4. make sure you run SET search_path = "my_schema";

Comment: Tried all the 4 points mentioned, is there any more config which we need to add when we run db inside the container ?

Comment: can you come ol on slack ? we can discuss more.

Comment: Sure, available on slack

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147409/unable-to-connect-corda-node-to-postgres-with-ssl possible avenue to investigate

Answer (score 0):

Following things has been discussed

1. Dinesh's team is not usign helm.
2. They have direct templates for each services.
3. Their psql version is 9.6.
4. They have set this deployment on prem not on cloud.
5. They can telnet the db container.
6. The db is inside the cluster. They can telnet it from cluster, but takes a little time like 4-5 sec. (This should ideally not take so much time)
7. They have Freebird VM created. All are part of the cluster and CENM service is already able to connect to the DB container. Problem is only with connecting to the node.

Few recommendations made

1. Within the same namespace as the node, deploy a busybox container
2. kubectl exec into this busybox instance and "ping" the database using the same IP/service name as the node is using
3. check the responses from the ping

They tried the above suggestion but it still takes around 40 sec and then later gives sockettimeoutexception timeout.
They even tried to increase the timeout like this jdbc:postgresql://10.96.0.50:5432/partyadb?loginTimeout=60000&connectTimeout=60000&socketTimeout=60000&cancelSignalTimeout=1200 , but still no luck.

**Our conclusions**

If it takes 4-5 seconds just to communicate with the VM - corda will never work. 
This is an issue with their Kubernetes deployment, there's not much we can do . If it's taking 40seconds to ping, it's nothing to do with corda.

Answer (score 0):

1. Deploy node DB and run migration script for each participant (tools-database-manager-4.4.jar)
2. Use Cluster IP for the DB, this gives freedom to use standard ports for all participants
3. Make sure there are no 2 pods running on same VM with different Cluster IP's or combination of both

In our case we were running corda node and DB on same VM, were node was using NodePort and DB was using ClusterIP. This is Hybrid setup where containers in cluster take time to locate the address due to mixture of NodePort and ClusterIP