# Error While Setting up the PostgreSQL database instead of default H2

Tags: postgresql, h2, corda

I'm trying to setup the postgresql database instead of default H2 database **on development environment**  and I'm following the below resource

https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/database_migration_tutorial/database-migration-tutorial

While starting the nodes, getting some errors related to unknown properties (**runMigration=true, database schema="schema name"**)

As I noticed on the above link, we need to have an enterprise jar to setup the same, so is it mandatory to have the Corda enterprise jar **on dev** to switch to postgresql database? if no, could you please let me know how can I proceed with the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The samples you're referencing are a little old, unfortunately.

If you want to use postgres you generally only need to specify that in the node gradle config file:

Something like this:

```
node {

    ...

    extraConfig = [
        dataSourceProperties: [
                dataSourceClassName : "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource",
                'dataSource.url' : "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/nodedb",
                'dataSource.user' : "postgres",
                'dataSource.password' : "pa$$w0rd"
        ],
        database: [
                transactionIsolationLevel : "READ_COMMITTED"
        ]
    ]
}
```

You may also want to add the runSchemaMigration=true like they do in this example: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/blob/release-V4/build.gradle#L103

Some useful resources for you:

- [Using PostgreSQL instead of H2 as the Corda node's database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419854/using-postgresql-instead-of-h2-as-the-corda-nodes-database)
- This corda blog post: https://www.corda.net/blog/cordapp-database-setup-development-perspective/